# $2^{O(n)} = O(2^n)$ solution verification

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, asymptotics

$2^{O(n)} = O(2^n)$

I'm familiar  with problems that only have one $O$ on one side but I'm not sure about this one. $f(n) = O(g(n))$ means $\exists n_0,C: |f(n)| \leq C \cdot g(n) \space\forall n \geq n_0$ or $\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f(n)/g(n)| < \infty.$

So we get $2^{O(n)} \leq C \space\cdot 2^n$. Let $C = 1$, so we get $2^{O(n)} = 2^n$.

Then we basically get $O(n) = n$. I heard that it isn't allowed to write the $O$ on the left side of an equation for some reason, I have absolutely no idea why. But $n \leq C_2 n$ is obviously true if we allow it. Soooo is this fine? Is it really not allowed to have the $O$ on the left side or is it just not "wanted"?

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me but I'm still confused, $n=O(n)$ is true but where did I go wrong in my solution?

Comment: The correct statement is $O(2^n)\subset2^{O(n)}$. In particular, $4^n\in2^{O(n)}\setminus O(2^n)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to get confused by the abuse of notation: $f(n) = O(g(n))$. What you should really think here is that $O(g(n))$ is the **set** of functions $h$ for which a constant $C$ and a natural number $n_{0}$ can be found for which $|h(k)|\leq C g(k)$ for all $k\geq n_0$.

Consequentially, $f(n) = O(g(n))$ is better read as $f(n)\in O(g(n))$. This should partially explain why $O(n) = n$ does not make sense, because it would say that any function $h(n)\in O(n)$ must be $h(n) = n$, which is clearly false since $\log(n)\in O(n)$ for instance.

Now, having big oh "$O$" on both sides requires a suitable interpretation of what is meant since the standard notation is $f(n) = O(g(n))$. However, a suitable interpretation of what $2^{O(n)} = O(2^n)$ means is that the set of all functions $g(n) = 2^{O(n)}$ also satisfy $g(n) = O(2^{n})$.

Your proof is incorrect because you need to show that every function $h(n)= 2^{O(n)}$ (remember this is $h(n) \in 2^{O(n)}$) satisfies $|h(n)| \leq C 2^{n}$ for some $C$ and all $n \geq n_0$. Choosing $C=1$ won't do you any good since $h(n) = 2^{2n} = 2^{O(n)}$ which can not be bounded by $2^{n}$. Even if you choose another constant $C$: $2^{2n} \leq C2^{n}$ can not be true for sufficiently large $n$. This provides a sufficient example to conclude that $2^{O(n)} = O(2^{n})$ is false.

I suggest, which was perhaps intended, that you try to prove that $O(2^{n})=2^{O(n)}$ instead, that is: any function $f(n) = O(2^n)$ must also satisfy $f(n) = 2^{O(n)}$.